# Le « record d'audience » et l'« audience record » ?

Tags: sens, anglais, adjectifs, formulation, nom-composé

> [À LA UNE À 18H] Les autorités russes ont arrêté aujourd’hui une
> proche alliée de l'opposant emprisonné Alexeï Navalny, tout en tentant
> de juguler des appels à manifester alimentés par le **record
> d'audience** d'une [enquête](https://youtu.be/ipAnwilMncI) accusant Vladimir Poutine de
> corruption. ([AFP](https://twitter.com/afpfr/status/1352300276099784710), avec lien vers l'enquête)

On dit que sous l'influence de la langue anglaise, le mot [audience](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=audience&id=1948) signifie depuis un bon moment aussi plus spécifiquement « nombre de personnes touchées par un média » (BDL).

Y a-t-il une différence entre *[record](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/record) d'audience* et *audience* [*record*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=3594) ; trouve-t-on les deux acceptables, justes en contexte, ou non et pourquoi ; pouvait-on employer *auditoire* dans un tel contexte ; y avait-il une manière plus claire de formuler la phrase ?

Comment: Pour moi il y a une légère différence: 'Record d'audience' représente la meilleure audience à ce jour alors qu' 'Audience record' représente une des meilleures audiences. Je ne suis pas sûr qu' 'audience' ait été influencé par l'anglais, je ne l'ai jamais entendu comme synonyme de 'public' en France métropolitaine par exemple.

Comment: @vc "S'adresser à l'audience" est assez courant pour "S'adresser au public" il me semble

Comment: @LaurentS. Assez rare en France métropolitaine, il me semble que c'est surtout utilisé au Québec.

Comment: Le « nombre de personnes touchées par un média », qui est un des deux sens influencés par l'anglais, et celui dont je traite, n'est pas le même sens que l' « auditoire ». Svp relire http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=audience&id=1948

Comment: @Thélée_Lavoie Dans ce cas je suis d'accord

Comment: @vc74 Le premier commentaire avec un peu de chair autour peut certainement constituer une réponse, indépendamment de la nuance dont on vient de traiter.

Comment: @Thélée_Lavoie Je n'en suis pas si sûr, ce n'est qu'un avis local, pas une réponse absolue. Je me demande même si 'Record d'audience' n'est pas parfois synonyme de 'un des records d'audience' rendant les lignes encore plus floues (ça c'est un anglicisme ;)).

Comment: Il me semble que audience record est de toute manière un anglicisme car c'est un groupe nominal  constitué de deux noms communs juxtaposés (on devrait presque dire audiance-record) alors qu'il me semble, et en restant prudent, qu'en français "historique" un nom commun ne peut pas qualifier un autre nom commun de cette manière.

Comment: @Distic Il ne me semble pas que *femme médecin* ou *enfant prodige* puissent être taxés d'anglicismes. On trouve en français *temps record* ou *chiffre record* depuis une centaine d'années. L'ordre des mots est bien français (en anglais: *record time*, *record number*)

Answer (score 1):

Il faut d'abord souligner que la phrase est mal rédigée et très lourde. Il faudrait la découper en deux phrases.

Il faut ensuite reformuler la partie qui contient l'objet de la question : le terme *record d'audience* en cherchant un autre terme plus approprié / spécifique au média utilisé pour la diffusion.
Si l'enquête a été mise en ligne sur un site internet connu (e.g. Youtube est celui du lien indiqué), on pourrait parler d'*un nombre de vues record* au lieu de *record d'audience*.

Je propose de réécrire la phrase en deux :

1. Les autorités russes ont arrêté aujourd’hui une proche alliée de l'opposant emprisonné Alexeï Navalny.

Pour la seconde phrase, nous avons au moins deux possibilités :

2-a. Elles ont aussi en même temps tenté de juguler des appels à manifester alimentés par **le nombre de vues record d'une enquête** *visible sur Youtube* accusant Vladimir Poutine de corruption.

2-b. Elles ont aussi en même temps tenté de juguler des appels à manifester alimentés par **le nombre de vues record d'une enquête** *mise en ligne sur Youtube* accusant Vladimir Poutine de corruption.

Le terme ***le nombre de vues record*** pourrait être complété par le nombre arrondi de vues au moment de la rédaction de la dépêche AFP.